# How can I handle curve singularity in this NIntegrate integration?

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, calculus-and-analysis

Yesterday I asked a question about the **non converging integral**. Woods told me that it is due to the function which has a singularity along a line which passes through the integration region. 
([Why does this numeric integral fail to converge?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18854/why-does-this-numeric-integral-fail-to-converge))
Now the question is that how can I find a correct answer for this integral? Should I eliminate these singularities from the integral bound? 
How can I understand it is integrable singularity and gives convergent value or not?
I read **singularity handling** in documentation center, but I couldn't solve the problem using **Exclusions**.(http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#122144792)

function:

```
 Msq2[w1_, 
   w2_] := (12.8228 + 10.518/(0.948338 - 2.0134 w1 - 2.0134 w2) - 
     6.69841/(1.72935 - 2.0134 w1 - 2.0134 w2) - 
     57.4434/(2.01348 - 2.0134 w1 - 2.0134 w2) - 
     13.4997/(3.45415 - 2.0134 w1 - 2.0134 w2) + 
     9.50782 (1/(-0.110612 + 2.0134 w1) + 
        1/(-0.110612 + 2.0134 w2)) - 
     82.5202 (1/(1.14046 + 2.0134 w1) + 1/(1.14046 + 2.0134 w2)))^2;
```

The region of the integral:

```
rpp = RegionPlot[
   Re[r2] < mphy - w1 - w2 < Re[r1], {w1, .11, .4}, {w2, .11, .4},  
   BoundaryStyle -> Blue, FrameLabel -> {"w1", "w2"}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0];
```

Where:

```
r1 = Sqrt[0.283 + (Sqrt[-0.018769 + w1^2] + Sqrt[-0.018769 + w2^2])^2];
r2 = Sqrt[0.283 + (Sqrt[-0.018769 + w1^2] - Sqrt[-0.018769 + w2^2])^2];
mphy = 1.007;
```

Integration:

```
NIntegrate[
  Boole[Re[r2] < mphy - w1 - w2 < Re[r1]] 1/(64*Pi^3*mphy)*
   Msq2[w1, w2], {w1, w1min, w1max}, {w2, w2min, w2max}, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 14] // Chop
```

Where:

```
 w1min = w2min = Min@rpp[[1, 1, All, 1]];
 w1max = w2max = Max@rpp[[1, 1, All, 1]];
```

The green line is the singular curve which a part of it is in the integration region:

```
With[{sing = Solve[1/Msq2[w1, w2] == 0, {w1, w2}] /. Rule -> Equal}, 
 Show[rpp, ContourPlot[sing, {w1, 0, 1}, {w2, 0, 1}]]]
```

[image]

With the following code I can find the singular line, but I don't know how to eliminate this line from integration bound:

```
sing1 = Solve[
    1/Msq2[w1, w2] == 0 && w1min < w1 < w1max && w2min < w2 < w2max &&
      Re[r2] < mphy - w1 - w2 < Re[r1], {w1, w2}][[1, 1]] /. 
  Rule -> Equal
```

> ConditionalExpression[  w1 == 9.93345*10^-7 (474169.[VeryThinSpace]-
>   1.0067*10^6 w2), 
>    0.209029 < w2 < 0.261985]

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer.
I tried to use `Exclusions` but it doesn't seem to be reliable :

```
sing1 // Simplify
(* ConditionalExpression[w1 == 0.471013 - 1. w2, 0.209029 < w2 < 0.261985] *)

NIntegrate[Boole[Re[r2] < mphy - w1 - w2 < Re[r1]] 1/(64*Pi^3*mphy)*Msq2[w1, w2], 
  {w1, w1min, w1max}, {w2, w2min, w2max},  
  Exclusions -> {{1/Msq2[w1, w2] == 0, w1min < w1 < w1max && w2min < w2 < w2max && 
                  Re[r2] < mphy - w1 - w2 < Re[r1]}}]

(* 21.8701 *)

NIntegrate[Boole[Re[r2] < mphy - w1 - w2 < Re[r1]] 1/(64*Pi^3*mphy)*Msq2[w1, w2], 
  {w1, w1min, w1max}, {w2, w2min, w2max}, 
  Exclusions -> {{w1 == 0.4710132114830634` - 0.9999999999999999` w2, 
                  0.20902863354401882` < w2 < 0.2619845779390446`}}]

(* 4.32175*10^13 *)
```

Comment: @gatessucks: You are true. It is not reliable and NIntegrate still has errors about some singular points although it seems they are excluded. It is strange. May be there is sth. wrong or we don't have integrable singularity? I don't know how to fix it.